# Chrome: Display Image from external url in Rich notifications

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating Rich notifications and using external iconUrl for images, and it fails

```
var options = {
        type: "basic",
        title: title +  ' - ' + timestamp,
        message: lineItem,
        iconUrl: 'http://example.com/asgsdg.png'
      }

chrome.notifications.create((id++).toString(), options, function() {});
```

> Error: notifications.create: Unable to download all specified images.

For my extension I have following in CSP:

```
"content_security_policy": "image-src 'self' http://example.com/*; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"
```

It works well for standard notification

```
window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(..., 'http://example.com/image.png',...);
```

What am I doing wrong in Rich notifications that image icons dont work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome.experimental.notification (Rich notifications) and external URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185206/chrome-experimental-notification-rich-notifications-and-external-urls)

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your CSP: image-src should be img-src. Second, you should remove the wildcard in the URL. Your CSP should therefore read:

```
"content_security_policy": "img-src 'self' http://example.com/; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"
```

Alternatively, you could use the workaround described in [chrome.experimental.notification (Rich notifications) and external URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185206/chrome-experimental-notification-rich-notifications-and-external-urls/18012086#18012086):

```
var options = {
    type: "basic",
    title: title +  ' - ' + timestamp,
    message: lineItem
  }

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://example.com/asgsdg.png");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function(){
    var blob = this.response;
    options.iconUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    chrome.notifications.create((id++).toString(), options, function() {});
};
xhr.send(null);
```

You can find more information on the Google Chrome extension documentation: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html#cross-origin

Comment: that's a workaround. Im surprised why doesnt it work through permissions (CSP).

Comment: Can you try changing your CSP declaration from "image-src" to "img-src"? It might be a typo cf https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#img-src

Comment: You need to specify url in permissions and it will work. 
`"permissions": [
    "*://domain.com/*"
  ],`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Chrome 52:

#### manifest.json

```
"permissions":[
  "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/*"
]
```

Then the following URLs worked:

```
chrome.notifications.create({
  title: 'Hey',
  message: 'Hello',
  iconUrl: 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1407390?'
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To show extenal images in the notifications the user should accept the permission. In the          manifest you have to put:

```
 "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "http:///","https:///"
  ]
```

Or only the external web you need instead of "*"

If you can copy the image to the extension folder and then you won't need this, but I suppose you can't.﻿